# changing order of Tuples in list

Tags: list, tuples

I have the following question.

Two separate list with tuples inside:

```
list1 = [('hello', 'world'), ('life', 'sun'), ('hello', 'hello')]
list2 = [('world', 'hello'), ('life', 'sun'), ('goodbye', 'hello')]
```

I want to return:

```
[('hello', 'world'), ('life', 'sun')]
```

Сould also be `('world', 'hello')` instead of `('hello', 'world')`

I have tried `intersection` and `set`. But that excludes `('hello', 'world'), ('world', 'hello')` cause they are not the same `different order`. But I want to return the combination.
i.e. `('hello', 'world')` is the same as `('world', 'hello')` for my purpose.

Thank you for your time.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort each tuple before forming the sets:

```
set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in list1) & set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in list2)
```

evaluates to

```
{('hello', 'world'), ('life', 'sun')}
```

The point is that e.g. `tuple(sorted('world','hello')) = ('hello','world')` (with the elements of the tuple occurring in alphabetical order).